# How would you migrate a large list of (taxonomy) vocabulary list?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, features

I'm moving a large series of vocabulary lists to a new D7 install. I used features to copy over taxonomy groups. However, I only copied over the taxonomy not the vocabulary lists. Is there an extension to features to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) did the trick. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to import or export taxonomy from or to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.
>
> It helps you to quick import a non-standardized vocabulary, for example an old thesaurus, a hierarchical taxonomy or a simple list of children, synonyms, descriptions, weights or related terms to terms. It can be used as a module or as an API with a plug-in mechanism. It can manage internationalized vocabularies with i18n_taxonomy, a submodule of [i18n module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) [Drupal 7 only].

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it quite for this purpose, but the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module will import from CSV files and can create taxonomy terms.  The Drupal 7 version still says it is alpha status, but I have been using it for a while now without any real problems with CSV files.

Just make sure your CSV is UTF-8 clean, otherwise you may get some obscure SQL errors if your data has characters with diacriticals, etc.